# Si no recibo respuestas en la pregunta con recompensa, ¿que pasa con esa recompensa?

Tags: soporte, recompensas

Hace un tiempo inicié una recompensa y la pregunta en cuestión trata un lenguaje no muy visto en la comunidad, por lo que, no he recibido respuestas aún y lo más probable por preguntas formuladas anteriormente es que no reciba respuesta. Por ende, ¿quién recibe dicha recompensa?

Tal y como se indica en el [Centro de Ayuda -> privilegio "ofrecer recompensas"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties):

> ...Si no otorgas tu recompensa en 7 días (más el periodo de gracia),
>   la respuesta más votada publicada tras el ofrecimiento con una
>   puntuación mínima de 2 recibirá la mitad del importe de la
>   recompensa. Si hay dos respuestas o más que cumplan los criterios y
>   tengan la misma puntuación, la respuesta más antigua se llevará la
>   recompensa. Si no hay ninguna respuesta que cumpla los criterios, la
>   recompensa quedará sin otorgar...

en el caso concreto expuesto anteriormente la única respuesta posee un -2 de votación. Gracias

Comment: Pasa lo que dice exactamente lo que escribiste...

Comment: Por si no queda claro: *la recompensa quedará sin otorgar...*, y eso no significa que te retornen la reputación ofrecida como recompensa.

Comment: @MauricioContreras yo creo que tu comentario da para una respuesta!

Comment: Se pierde, pero es importante otorgar la recompensa ùnicamente a la respuesta que haya aportado una soluciòn, ya que si la otorgas a una respuesta que tal vez es mala, esto no serìa en realidad de ayuda a la comunidad.